# What to pass as a Sender in a button OnClick method?

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder

I have a function that creates a button dynamically

```
void createBtn(News obj,TForm *Form1){
    TButton *spam = new TButton(Form1);
    spam->Parent = newsCard;
    spam->Position->X = 280;
    spam->Position->Y = 256;
    spam->Text = "Spam";
}
```

I need to assign an `OnClick` event to it, so I added the following line to the function above:

```
spam->OnClick = spamClick;
```

The code for spamClick is:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::spamClick(TObject *Sender, News obj)
 {
    allUsers[userIndex].spamNews(obj);
    ShowMessage("Done!");
 }
```

The problem is, I need to pass the `obj` in the line, but the function requires 2 arguments, which are the `Sender` and the `obj`.

```
spam->OnClick = spamClick(obj); // error here
```

But I do not know what to pass. I've tried `Form1`, `spam`, and `newsCard`. But nothing works.

What do I pass as a `Sender`? Or, is there a way to assign an OnClick event to the button inside `createBtn()`?

Edit:
class News has the following definition

```
class News
{
public:
    News(string, string, string, Dates);
    string title;
    string description;
    Dates date;
    int rate;
    string category;
    vector<Comment> comments;
    int spamCount;
    static int newsCount;
    int newsID;
    int numOfRatedUsers;
};
```

and spamNews is a function in the user class that pushes the obj.newsID into a vector in the user then increases the spamCount.

```
void user::spamNews(News& obj) {
//check that the news in not already spammed 
    if(!findNews(spammedNews,obj)){  
        spammedNews.push_back(obj.newsID);
        obj.spamCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach doesn't work, because you are trying to *call* `spamClick()` first and then assign its return value to the `OnClick` event.

Your first approach is the correct way, however you can't add parameters to the `OnClick` event handler.

`TButton` has `Tag...` properties for holding user-defined data. However, since the `News` object is not being passed around by pointer, the `Tag...` properties are not very helpful in this case (unless the `News` object is held in an array/list whose index can then be stored in the `Tag`).

Otherwise, I would suggest deriving a new class from `TButton` to hold the `News` object, eg:

```
class TMyButton : public TButton
{
public:
    News NewsObj;

    __fastcall TMyButton(TComponent *Owner, const News &obj)
        : TButton(Owner), NewsObj(obj) {}
};

void TForm1::createBtn(const News &obj)
{
    TMyButton *spam = new TMyButton(this, obj);
    spam->Parent = newsCard;
    spam->Position->X = 280;
    spam->Position->Y = 256;
    spam->Text = _D("Spam");
    spam->OnClick = &spamClick;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::spamClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    MyButton *btn = static_cast<TMyButton*>(Sender);
    allUsers[userIndex].spamNews(btn->NewsObj);
    ShowMessage(_D("Done!"));
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Since your `News` objects are being stored in a `vector` that you are looping through, then a simpler solution would be to pass the `News` object to `createBtn()` by *reference* and then store a *pointer* to that object in the `TButton::Tag` property, eg:

```
void TForm1::createBtn(News &obj)
{
    TButton *spam = new TButton(this);
    spam->Parent = newsCard;
    spam->Position->X = 280;
    spam->Position->Y = 256;
    spam->Text = _D("Spam");
    spam->Tag = reinterpret_cast<NativeInt>(&obj);
    spam->OnClick = &spamClick;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::spamClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TButton *btn = static_cast<TButton*>(Sender);
    News *obj = reinterpret_cast<News*>(btn->Tag);
    allUsers[userIndex].spamNews(*obj);
    ShowMessage(_D("Done!"));
}
```

Or, using the `TMyButton` descendant:

```
class TMyButton : public TButton
{
public:
    News *NewsObj;

    __fastcall TMyButton(TComponent *Owner)
        : TButton(Owner) {}
};

void TForm1::createBtn(News &obj)
{
    TMyButton *spam = new TMyButton(this);
    spam->Parent = newsCard;
    spam->Position->X = 280;
    spam->Position->Y = 256;
    spam->Text = _D("Spam");
    spam->NewsObj = &obj;
    spam->OnClick = &spamClick;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::spamClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    MyButton *btn = static_cast<TMyButton*>(Sender);
    allUsers[userIndex].spamNews(*(btn->NewsObj));
    ShowMessage(_D("Done!"));
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error " no matching constructor for initialization of 'TForm1::TMyButton' " also "candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided "

Comment: @Ruqaiyah see the update I just posted.

Comment: the previous errors are gone with the update you posted, but it gives this errors instead "constructor for 'TForm1::TMyButton' must explicitly initialize the member 'obj' which does not have a default constructor" and  "member is declared here" and "News is declared here".

Comment: @Ruqaiyah I have made another update. It would have really helped if you had provided a [mcve] showing the definition of `News` and how `createBtn()` is being called.

Comment: it worked well, thank you. but how can I pass obj by reference so the original obj have catches the changes ? createBtn() is called in a while loop over a vector of News.

Comment: @Ruqaiyah You updated your question to show what `spamNews()` looks like, but not how `createBtn()` is being called. But whatever. I have updated my answer, again.